# Two float list - one below the other

Tags: css, css-float

I have two float list one from the right and one from the left. The left float list is on top and the right on bottom. I want the right to be below the left like this:

[image]

However, my code produces this:

[image]

How can I force the left float list not to break? And why does it break anyway? This is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Floats dont like me.</TITLE>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
     .small { height:20px;width:65px;border:solid;float:left;margin-left:10px;margin-  top:10px }
     .smallR { height:20px;width:65px;border:solid;float:right;margin-right:10px;margin-top:50px; }
  </style>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<div style='width:300px;height:100px;border:solid'>
<div class='smallR' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
</div></BODY></HTML>
```

Comment: FYI, `margin-  top:10px` should be `margin-top:10px`

Comment: This reiterates what @codehorse posted http://jsfiddle.net/3UsW2/

Comment: @BuddhistBeast thanks but this is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

The reason it isn't working is likely because you have width: 300px; Change it to around 360px to see if it works then. IF it works, you can always lower the px till it works just how you want precisely.

```
<div style='width:300px;height:100px;border:solid'> // change the width to like 360px;
<div class='smallR' ></div> // if for some reason changing width: 300px to 360px; doesn't work then put this div as the last one
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
                               //would put here if changing width don't work
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but than they are not below each other but beside each other.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this should work.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3UsW2/2/)

Now, why did it not work before?

Simple. It's because of the way you ordered your divs. Let's take a look at your original code:

```
<div style='width:300px;height:100px;border:solid'>
<div class='smallR' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
<div class='small' ></div>
</div>
```

What is this asking the browser to interpret? It's asking for the very first div to be positioned as far right as possible and for the following three divs to fit in the line but be positioned as far left. Why doesn't it work? Because this is trying to fit all 4 divs in one line. It isn't able to because your very first div is already positioned at the far right, causing any div that won't fit on the left to be positioned one row down (this is also the reason why you had to use the margin-top to position that far right div).

Simple. Take a look at this code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class='small'></div>
    <div class='small'></div>
    <div class='small'></div>
    <div class='smallR'></div>
</div>
```

First, I replaced the ordering of the divs (this helps in the long run because it ensures that the first three will be on the first row, assuming you do not exceed the entire width of the container with the first three). Second, I alter the margin-top code, to position the div exactly where I want it, that way it does not touch any of the other divs. Here is the CSS code:

```
.smallR {
    height:20px;
    width:65px;
    border:solid;
    float:right;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

And just like that, its done :) Now, if nothing made sense, please let me know because I can go further in depth with a few things. Also, I would suggest looking into the [Almanac](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/) to give you some tricks of the trade :)